# extract line of file1.txt and merge to file2.txt using shell?

Tags: bash, shell, join, awk, sed

I have two files

file1.txt (generated by user registration)

```
1   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
2   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
3   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
4   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
```

file2.txt (generated by user job submission and has just 1 line)

```
CellPhone   MLSNUMBER   PRICE   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
```

The CellPhone number is always in the same format 3215551234 in both files

I would like to search file1.txt for the CellPhone number and add that complete particular line to the beginning of file2.txt

I have gotten this far with awk and sed over the last day or so but this has me stumped. I  believe awk and join is the way, but this is way outside my skill level.

Comment: does `join file1.txt file2.txt -1 4 -2 1` produce what you want?

Answer (score 0):

`join` changes your fields around and requires sorted files. It sounds like you are looking for something more like this:

```
grep " $(awk '{print $1}' file2.txt) " file1.txt|cat - file2.txt
```

Assuming there are spaces around the CellPhone number in file1.txt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search `file1.txt` for cellphone number in `file2.txt`:

```
$ awk '
  # Only runs on the first file (file2.txt)
  NR==FNR {
    # Register each phone number in an array
    cp[$1]=1
    # Skip the next part of the execution
    next
  }
  # Only running for file1.txt
  # Check to see if the phone number in file1.txt is in the array
  $4 in cp # This is a short way of writing: $4 in cp {print $0};
' file2.txt file1.txt
1   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
2   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
3   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
4   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
```

If you want to concatenate `file2.txt` at the end you can simply write `| cat - file2.txt`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{cp[$1]=1;next}$4 in cp' file2.txt file1.txt | cat - file2.txt
```

If you have multiply phone number in `file2.txt` and want the output to be:

```
1 Name1 Name2 Phone1 Email ...
2 Name1 Name2 Phone1 Email ...
Phone1   MLSNUMBER   PRICE   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
3 Name1 Name2 Phone2 Email ...
4 Name1 Name2 Phone2 Email ...
Phone2   MLSNUMBER   PRICE   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
```

You can use this if - assuming that `file1.txt` is pre sorted on the phone number:

```
$ awk '
  # Only runs on the first file (file2.txt)
  NR==FNR {
    # Register each phone number in an array
    cp[$1]=$0
    # Skip the next part of the execution
    next
  }
  # Print current line same as 1==1{print $0}
  1;
  FNR>1 && prev!=$4 {
    print prevLine
  }
  {
    prev=$4
    prevLine=cp[$4]
  }
  END {
    print prevLine
  }
' file2.txt file1.txt 
1 Name1 Name2 Phone1 Email ...
2 Name1 Name2 Phone1 Email ...
1   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
Phone1   MLSNUMBER   PRICE   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
2   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
3   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
4   Name1   Name2   CellPhone   Email   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
CellPhone   MLSNUMBER   PRICE   ANDANOTHER20FIELDS
```